docker-compose start Unable to obtain connection from database
When I do docker-compose up, everything works fine and I got no problems, the backend connects to the database successfully,
but when I do docker-compose stop and immediately after docker-compose start the backend can't connect to the database again , even with the database working.
I've tested database after the backend error with queries to see if there's some problem but everything is working fine
and it's not because the database is not ready to connections because the shop container depends on postgresdb container and I've tried to run shop container after the error and after tested postgresdb container with queries
docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.8"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:16.2
    container_name: postgresdb
    networks:
      - compose-shop
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./init-db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.sql

  shop:
    image: danielschiavo/shop:1.0.0
    container_name: shop
    networks:
      - compose-shop
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - filestorage:/home/shop/imagens
    depends_on:
      - postgres

networks:
  compose-shop:
    driver: bridge
    
volumes:
  filestorage:

application-prod.properties:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb:5432/shop
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

log error:
daniel@DANIEL-PC:~/shop$ docker run -it danielschiavo/shop:1.0.0 bash

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.4)

2024-04-09T03:12:02.777Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] b.c.danielschiavo.shop.ShopApplication   : Starting ShopApplication v1.0.0 using Java 21 with PID 1 (/Shop/shop-1.0.0.jar started by root in /Shop)
2024-04-09T03:12:02.779Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] b.c.danielschiavo.shop.ShopApplication   : The following 1 profile is active: "prod"
2024-04-09T03:12:03.806Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-04-09T03:12:03.891Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 78 ms. Found 8 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-04-09T03:12:04.412Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-04-09T03:12:04.423Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-04-09T03:12:04.423Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.19]
2024-04-09T03:12:04.453Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-04-09T03:12:04.454Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1607 ms
2024-04-09T03:12:04.546Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-04-09T03:12:07.658Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:354) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:263) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration.setDataSource(ClassicConfiguration.java:1094) ~[flyway-core-9.22.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration.dataSource(FluentConfiguration.java:624) ~[flyway-core-9.22.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.configureDataSource(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:185) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.flyway(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:172) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1165) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:682) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1165) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1685) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1434) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:210) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:173) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:168) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:153) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:266) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:240) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:52) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4866) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:845) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:921) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:437) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:105) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:499) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:218) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:188) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:618) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at br.com.danielschiavo.shop.ShopApplication.main(ShopApplication.java:15) ~[!/:1.0.0]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91) ~[shop-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53) ~[shop-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) ~[shop-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgresdb
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:567) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:751) ~[na:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:243) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:132) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
        ... 116 common frames omitted

2024-04-09T03:12:07.728Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 9.22.3 by Redgate
2024-04-09T03:12:07.728Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : See release notes here: https://rd.gt/416ObMi
2024-04-09T03:12:07.728Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    :
2024-04-09T03:12:07.748Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-04-09T03:12:08.749Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:354) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:263) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297) ~[postgresql-42.6.2.jar!/:42.6.2]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:48) ~[flyway-core-9.22.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:74) ~[flyway-core-9.22.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:142) ~[flyway-core-9.22.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:140) ~[flyway-core-9.22.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:682) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]


you can try to create the docker network with an identified gateway and subnet first like this " --gateway 172.200.0.1 --subnet 172.200.0.0/24", and then start the compose

Your error log doesn't come from a docker-compose run.

That error is surprising to me mostly because I'd expect docker-compose stop would leave containers in an unusual stopped-but-existing state, and the error suggests the database container no longer exists.  Does docker-compose down; docker-compose up -d work better?  That will delete and recreate the containers.  (You may need to add a volume to the database container to persist its state.)

when I do docker-compose up the backend can connect to database, but when I turn the compose off with docker-compose stop then after I turn on with docker-compose start the backend can't connect to database again, even if I try to run the shop container after it fails
@datawookie the command docker run it's a try after docker-compose start fails but it's the same error
@DavidMaze I want everything works correctly, I don't want to work around, with detached argument happens the same

I made a misstake on the code where the backend was trying to insert data into a table that is unique
Sorry everyone, thanks
package br.com.danielschiavo.shop.infra.inserirdados;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import br.com.danielschiavo.shop.models.cliente.Cliente;
import br.com.danielschiavo.shop.models.cliente.Cliente.ClienteBuilder;
import br.com.danielschiavo.shop.models.cliente.role.NomeRole;
import br.com.danielschiavo.shop.models.cliente.role.Role;
import br.com.danielschiavo.shop.models.cliente.role.Role.RoleBuilder;
import br.com.danielschiavo.shop.repositories.cliente.ClienteRepository;

@Profile("prod")
@Component
public class InicializacaoProdEnv implements CommandLineRunner {
    
    @Autowired
    private ClienteRepository clienteRepository;
    
    private ClienteBuilder clienteBuilder = Cliente.builder();
    private RoleBuilder roleBuilder = Role.builder();
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        inserirDado();
    }

    public void inserirDado() {
        boolean resultado = clienteRepository.findByCpf("14330283794").isEmpty();
        
        if (resultado == true) {
            Cliente cliente = clienteBuilder
                    .id(null)
                    .cpf("12345678912")
                    .nome("Daniel")
                    .sobrenome("Schiavo Rosseto")
                    .dataNascimento(LocalDate.of(2000, 3, 3))
                    .dataCriacaoConta(LocalDate.now())
                    .email("daniel.schiavo35@gmail.com")
                    .senha("$2a$12$g/401MRFl.y7b4x5jOPjeu5d31oI9a.uI9WL1pWXR.0ocFj9J/DNu")
                    .celular("27996121255")
                    .fotoPerfil("Padrao.jpeg")
                    .adicionarRole(roleBuilder.id(null)
                            .role(NomeRole.ADMIN).build())
                    .getCliente();
            
            clienteRepository.save(cliente);
        }
    }
}



This looks like you have a race condition between your containers.
I suggest setting up a dependency from your client service on the health of the database service.
In the docker-compose.yml below there's

a healthcheck on the database service so that it will only be flagged as "healthy" when it is ready to accept connections and
a depends_on in the client service so that it will only proceed when the database is ready to accept connections.

The client service is just a placeholder and should be adapted to your shop service. It connects to the database and executes a simple query. Take this stack up and down a few times to satisfy yourself that communication between the services is robust.
version: "3.8"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:16.2
    container_name: postgresdb
    networks:
      - compose-shop
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  client:
    image: postgres:16.2
    container_name: client
    networks:
      - compose-shop
    environment:
      - PGPASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    command: sh -c "psql -h postgres -U postgres -c 'SELECT * from pg_user;'"

networks:
  compose-shop:
    driver: bridge


As I said friend: there is no race condition because when I did docker-compose start and the shop container failed to start, in that time, I entered into postgresdb container and tested it with queries to see if the postgresdb was working, and it was working, I was able to do SELECTS and all. Then I tried to start the shop container again with docker run shop because I thinked the same thing as you and I got the same error, so isn't race condition.

Looking more carefully at your error log:
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgresdb

What host are you using in your connection string from the client?
It looks like you are using postgresdb as the host name for the database. That corresponds to the container_name set for that service. However, the container name does not translate into the network name. You should rather use the service name, postgres, as the host name for the database. If you look at the test command in my other answer, psql -h postgres -U postgres -c 'SELECT * from pg_user;', then you see the -h postgres argument is specifying the name of the database service to connect to. You need to do something similar in your client code. Just change postgresdb to postgres and you should be sorted.

I tried, got the same problem, when I do docker-compose up the backend can connect to database, but when I turn the compose off with docker-compose stop then after I turn on with docker-compose start the backend can't connect to database again, even if I try to run the shop container after it fails

Okay, can you please update the error log in your question with the error that you get after making this change?
